# Alignedat for 3 equations in one line

Tags: equations, align, alignment

I need to use "alignedat" to write my equations as pictured for an assignment. I cannot find the syntax anywhere that is helpful for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! What "pictured" are you referring to?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
1+1=& 2 & 2=&1+1 & 1=2-1
\end{align*}
\end{document}` ? please, show us, what you try so far! welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Oh, @Zarko awoke from hibernation ;-)

Comment: @marmot, yes, I was awakened by the shouting of our fans when we beat the USA and Slovakia in the hockey ... :-)

Comment: @Zarko Actually, I'd have shouted for Slovenia.

Comment: @Mico: Some rare times, it may happen it's better…

Comment: You might replace ‘never’ with ‘most of the time’. It's the same type of  problem  as using or not vertical rules in tables: usually, it's  not recommenced, except for some special designs. For alignments, one may have to align  parentheses or some symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Using `align*`, `alignat*`, or `alignedat` seems pointless for three equations to be typeset in one row. Using one of these environments only makes sense if you have two or more rows.

I'd simply use `\hspace{<length>}` to indicate the desired distances between the equations. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
\[
1+1=2 \hspace{0.75in} 2=1+1 \hspace{0.75in} 1=2-1 
\]
\end{document}
```